# To what are the scriptures referring when they speak of the books of the "chronicles of the kings"?

Tags: exegesis, 1-kings, 2-chronicles, 1-chronicles

In the books of 1 and 2 Kings, there are quite a few places where the author refers to "the Book of the Chronicles of the Kings of Judah" or "the Book of the Chronicles of the Kings of Israel".

> "Now the rest of the acts of Jeroboam, how he made war and how he reigned, behold, they are written in **the Book of the Chronicles of the Kings of Israel**.  1 Kings 14:19 NASB
>
> Now the rest of the acts of Rehoboam and all that he did, are they not written in **the Book of the Chronicles of the Kings of Judah**? 1 Kings 14:29 NASB

Immediately following the books of 1 and 2 Kings are two books referred to as 1 and 2 Chronicles.  Are these the books to which 1 and 2 Kings refer or are they referring to other books that are not in the Bible and/or maybe lost to us?

Comment: This  [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_the_Kings_of_Judah) says that it is lost. I'm also confused about this. Good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following books are referenced in the King James Version of the bible but are not found in that text.[(source)](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/bd/lost-books?lang=eng)

- book of the Wars of the Lord ([Num. 21:14](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/num/21.14?lang=eng#13));
- book of Jasher ([Josh. 10:13](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/josh/10.13?lang=eng#12); [2 Sam. 1:18](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-sam/1.18?lang=eng#17));
- book of the acts of Solomon ([1 Kgs. 11:41](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/1-kgs/11.41?lang=eng#40));
- book of Samuel the seer ([1 Chr. 29:29](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/1-chr/29.29?lang=eng#28));
- book of Gad the seer ([1 Chr. 29:29](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/1-chr/29.29?lang=eng#28));
- book of Nathan the prophet ([1 Chr. 29:29](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/1-chr/29.29?lang=eng#28); [2 Chr. 9:29](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/9.29?lang=eng#28));
- prophecy of Ahijah ([2 Chr. 9:29](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/9.29?lang=eng#28));
- visions of Iddo the seer ([2 Chr. 9:29](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/9.29?lang=eng#28); [12:15](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/12.15?lang=eng#14); [13:22](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/13.22?lang=eng#21));
- book of Shemaiah ([2 Chr. 12:15](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/12.15?lang=eng#14));
- book of Jehu ([2 Chr. 20:34](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/20.34?lang=eng#33));
- sayings of the seers ([2 Chr. 33:19](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/33.19?lang=eng#18));
- an epistle of Paul to the Corinthians, earlier than our present 1
  Corinthians ([1 Cor. 5:9](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-cor/5.9?lang=eng#8));
- possibly an earlier epistle to the Ephesians ([Eph. 3:3](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/3.3?lang=eng#2));
- an epistle to the Church at Laodicea ([Col. 4:16](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/col/4.16?lang=eng#15));
- and some prophecies of Enoch, known to Jude ([Jude 1:14](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/jude/1.14?lang=eng#13)).

<sub>(Though you can of course look up each scripture to verify for yourself as a link has been provided for each.)</sub>

`The Book of the Chronicles of the Kings of Judah` [is believed to be a record kept by the kings of Israel](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0004_0_03323.html) but it is not considered to be the books we know as 1 and 2 Chronicles.

---

<sub>Interestingly enough, this is pretty conclusive that our bible today isn't quite what it used to be, and that there are prophets (like Nathan and [Shemaiah](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/1-kgs/12.22?lang=eng#21)) that recorded the word of God, but that word has since been lost to us.</sub>